# markdown-it render returning string but html not being parsed

Tags: reactjs, markdown

I am using [markdown-it](https://github.com/markdown-it/markdown-it) to parse markup documents.  My code is as follows:

```
import React from 'react';
import Markdown from 'markdown-it';

const md = new Markdown();

export default () => {
  return (
    <div>
    {
      md.render('# markdown-it rulezz!')
    }
    </div>
  );
}
```

The h1 being returned is correct, but the output is not registering as an h1; the h1 is considered part of the string - it's not being recognized as a tag.  See attachment.  Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong here?  Thanks!

[image]

Comment: `__dangerouslySetInnerHTML`?

Comment: Thanks!  That is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use:

```
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: md.render('# markdown-it rulezz!')}}></div>
```

Here's reference: https://zhenyong.github.io/react/tips/dangerously-set-inner-html.html

Or you can you use [react-markdown](https://zhenyong.github.io/react/tips/dangerously-set-inner-html.html)

Comment: Thanks!  That is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

No problem when using it like this ;

```
<p dangerouslySetInnerHTML={ {__html: PostItem.Content} } />
```

But when he does this, he gives an error

```
<p dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: md.render(PostItem.Content)}}></p>
```

The error message is as follows ;

> Error: Input data should be a String